# Get or create on a single form field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have 3 fields in a model:

```
class Visitor(models.Model):
    visitor_company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    visitor_name = models.CharField(default='', max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
    visitor_email = models.EmailField(default='', max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
```

I want to create a ModelForm that first checks if `visitor_email` is unique and if so, simply updates `visitor_company` and `visitor_name`, otherwise creates a new entry.

What logic or functions should I use? If I use `get_or_create`, then the logic would test all 3 fields to be identical, before it returns a get. I just want this to apply to `visitor_email`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you want `visitor_email` to be unique for each `Visitor`, then you should set `unique` constraint to `True` for that field:

```
visitor_email = models.EmailField(max_length=128, unique=True)
```

*Please note that, you can omit `blank=False`, `null=False` as they are default.*

---

As of *Django 1.7*, [`update_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update_or_create) was introduced;

> A convenience method for updating an object with the given *kwargs*, creating a new one if necessary. The **defaults** is a dictionary of (field, value) pairs used to update the object.

---

```
updated_fields = {'company': Company.objects.first(), 'visitor_name': 'John Doe'}
visitor, created = Visitor.objects.update_or_create(visitor_email='ozgur@example.org', defaults=defaults)
```

In order to use this approach in conjunction with a `Form`:

```
def view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.copy()

        form = VisitorForm(data)
        if form.is_valid():
            visitor, created = Visitor.objects.update_or_create(
                 visitor_email=data.pop('visitor_email'), defaults=data)
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I put this in a view to save the form?

Comment: @ozgur I don't know how much more efficient this approach is, but in my eyes(not experienced eyes) this approach looses in readability - personal opinion. But nice to have an option, tho, learned something new.

Comment: Thanks. This works if you remove `unique=true` as otherwise the form validation will fail if you are trying to update the record.

Comment: You may want to use Form instead of ModelForm.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something like:

```
try:
    email = Visitor.objects.get(visitor_email=email)
except Visitor.DoesNotExist:
    #create new one
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if Visitor.objects.get(visitor_email=email).exists():
    #Create new entry
 else: 
     #your logic for updating company and name
```